# RestSharp "The operation has timed out"

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, restsharp

I use RestSharp to execute POST request: `var response = client.Execute(request);`

This request returns an error exception is inside `response`: `{"The operation has timed out"}`.

What is the reason for this? How to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure remote endpoint, where you send POST, is OK? Try to send the same post with Fiddler or Postman.

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't found an answer yet, look at the Timeout property.  The HttpWebRequest default is 100 seconds and I haven't been able to find any data that suggests RestSharp changes the timeout default.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout(v=vs.110).aspx

In the following line of code, this would set the timeout to 5 minutes.

```
    request.Timeout = 300000;
```